# Disabling elements when deselecting a checkbox

Tags: javascript

I have a checkbox, a drop down list and a text box.
I want to disable the drop down and text box on deselecting the checkbox.
Following is what I have on my view -

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<%Html.CheckBox("chkCheckMe", new { enabled = Convert.ToBoolean(ViewData["ShowFlag"])}); %>>
<%Html.DropDownList("ddlModes", new SelectList(new string[]{"Auto", "Manual"}), new { enabled = Convert.ToBoolean(ViewData["ShowFlag"])}); %>
<%Html.TextBox("txtSample", new {enabled = Convert.ToBoolean(ViewData["ShowFlag"]) }); %>>
</asp:Content>
```

Can I do this using script?

Thanks,
Kapil

Comment: Yes, you can. If you update your question and include the code you have so far I´ll be happy to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        var c = document.getElementById("yourCheckboxID");
        c.onclick = toggleElements;
    }
    function toggleElements() {
        var c = document.getElementById("yourCheckboxID");
        var d = document.getElementById("yourDropDownID");
        var t = document.getElementById("yourTextBoxID");
        d.disabled = t.disabled = c.checked;
    }
</script>
```